# If G is a finite group of order $p^n k$, where $k<p$, G must contain a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove that if G is a finite group of order $p^n k$, where $k<p$, then G must contain a normal subgroup. I think I need to find a group $P$ such that $gPg^{-1}\subset G.$ But I really have no idea about how do I get that. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, but I don't know how do I apply them in this problem.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. Every group has a normal subgroup, and obviously $gPg^{-1}\leq G$ for any subgroup $P$.

Comment: @FrancisBegbie It asks for a non-trivial normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said in comments that you are familiar with Sylow's Theorem, let's go ahead and apply it.

Note that since $k < p$, then $p \nmid k$ so we can apply Sylow's Theorem. Now we know that $\text{Syl}_p (G)$ is nonempty, i.e. there exists at least one such Sylow subgroup. Furthermore, the number of such subgroups is $n_p \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $n_p \mid k$. Use that $k<p$ again to deduce that $n_p = 1$ exactly. Finally, use the second part of Sylow's Theorem which says in particular that any two Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate to deduce that this Sylow subgroup we found must be normal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By the Sylow Theorems 
$$n_p |k \mbox{ and } n_p \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

As $k <p$ this tells you exactly what $n_p$ is, and once you find it the rest is easy.